# Why is my program outputting different answers when I only adjust some of the lines that is irrelevant to the answer?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. I want to write a program that can determine whether the number counts in a row of an array equal another amount that is designate by the user.

Below is the initial code I wrote. It has the correct output, which are 0,0,0,3,4,5,0.

```
int dayoffLim = 0;
cin >> dayoffLim;   
int dayoffType[7][10] = {
                        {1, 2, 8, 9, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30}, 
                    {2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 30, 31}, 
                    {3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31, 0}, 
                    {4, 5, 11, 12, 18, 19, 25, 26, 0, 0}, 
                    {5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27, 0, 0}, 
                    {6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28, 0, 0},
                    {1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 23, 28, 29, 0}
                };

    
    if(days == 28){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=28 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                proDayoff[i] = i;
            }
            
        }
        
    }else if(days == 29){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=29 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
                
            }
            
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                proDayoff[i] = i;
            }
            
        }
            
    }else if(days == 30){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=30 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                proDayoff[i] = i;
            }
            
        }
            
    }else if(days == 31){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=31 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                proDayoff[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        cout << proDayoff[i] << " ";
    }
```

But I want the output to be like 3,4,5,0,0,0,0. So, I adjust the part of the changing index of "proDayoff" array, which is like the following:

```
int dayoffLim = 0, days = 0;
cin >> dayoffLim >> days;   
int dayoffType[7][10] = {
                        {1, 2, 8, 9, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30}, 
                    {2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 30, 31}, 
                    {3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31, 0}, 
                    {4, 5, 11, 12, 18, 19, 25, 26, 0, 0}, 
                    {5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27, 0, 0}, 
                    {6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28, 0, 0},
                    {1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 23, 28, 29, 0}
                };


    if(days == 28){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=28 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            
                        //Where I adjust
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                z++;
            }
            proDayoff[z] = i;

            
        }
        
    }else if(days == 29){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=29 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
                
            }
            
                        //Where I adjust
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                z++;
            }
            proDayoff[z] = i;

            
        }
            

    }else if(days == 30){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=30 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            
                        //Where I adjust
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                z++;
            }
            proDayoff[z] = i;

            
        }
            
    }else if(days == 31){
        int z = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int isDayoff = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                
                if(dayoffType[i][j] <=31 && dayoffType[i][j] != 0){
                    isDayoff ++;
                }
            }
            //Where I adjust
            if(isDayoff == dayoffLim){
                z++;
            }
            proDayoff[z] = i;
        }
    }
```

However, the output becomes 3,4,6,0,0,0,0! I don't know what happened......Could someone tell me what happened? Thank you so much!

The input of the variable "dayoffLim" and "days" are:

```
8 31
```

I've checked whether the initialization of "z" should be there, it indeed should be there. I'm confused that why is the first two output 3 and 4 still remain the output I want it to be, but the output 5 turns into 6. Thank you all for reading this question!

Comment: what is the code supposed to be calculating? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Please add that your code checks for each row, how many numbers are between 1 and the entered number of days (31). And compares that number for equality with dayoffLim (8). That this is true for rows 3, 4 and 5 (when beginning to count with 0 for the first row).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like

```
if(isDayoff == dayoffLim) {
    z++;
    proDayoff[z] = i;
}
```

instead of

```
if(isDayoff == dayoffLim) {
    z++;
}

proDayoff[z] = i;
```

(Moving writing `i` into the if block.)

Otherwise the write pointer is only advanced, if the condition is met, but the results are always written. So the last valid result is definitely overwritten with the last result (which is `6` in a for loop from `0..6`).

Please be aware that if the condition is `true` only for row `0`, the result would be `0 0 0 0 0 0 0`, the same, as if the condition was `false` for every row. You would have to compare `z` (the number of rows, for which the condition is `true`, minus `1`) to distinguish between the cases or use another number then `0` for unused result elements or start the row counting with `1`.